# refresh personalization value when close browser

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, personalization

I'm trying using personalization with profile card in sitecore 8. 
I create profile key, profile card, parttern card and assign to content item the personalization for it. it is working but i don't know why it can't keep old source when i close browser or open it in other browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by old source? Do you want to gather up all the profile points that you had in the old session? In Sitecore you have Session values and Contact values. The Session is this current session while the Contact is  all the past sessions together.

Comment: Yes, I mean how i can keep old points for visitor when they comeback to site

Comment: If you use the Behavioral Profiles of the main contact, you can add up the points for the profiles that they got before. Remember that each page can only be counted once against the profiles. So multiple hits to a behavioral profile is from multiple pages. 

http://dnstommy.github.io/images/Profiles.png

Comment: How can i add up the points for the profiles ? by coding ?  i think it auto save into mongodb and syns to xdb right ?

Comment: Yes in code. What you would need to figure out is how the pattern cards keep track of the scores to put the user into one. I think we are all still trying to learn as much as we can about this.

Here is the behavioral profiles in mongo. http://dnstommy.github.io/images/Mongo.png